# Nested Array in Firebase with jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I will be loading information into a JSON file and then importing it into firebase for it to load on my website. I have a sample JSON like this...

```
{
            "date": "date of event",
            "title": "title of event",
            "address": "address",
            "city": "city of event",
            "state": "HI",
            "zip": "11111",
            "available": true,
            "cost": "$60",
            "included": [
                "string1",
                "string2",
                "string3"
            ]
        }
```

I have the following code.

```
 database.ref().child('events').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      var content = '';
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        var val = child.val();
        content +='<tr>';
        content += '<td>' + val.date + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.title + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.address + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.city + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.state + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.zip + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.cost + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.included + '</td>';
        content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);

    }
  });
```

Everything is fine except for the included portion. Right now, this will print like `string1,string2,string3`. How would I loop through that array and either print them like..

> String 1
>
> String 2
>
> String 3

Or even convert the string values into img. For example, if we offer coffee, or food, it'll be an icon representing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over included array and add `td` to `content`.

```
database
  .ref()
  .child('events')
  .once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      var content = '';
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        var val = child.val();
        content += '<tr>';
        content += '<td>' + val.date + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.title + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.address + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.city + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.state + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.zip + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.cost + '</td>';
        val.included.forEach((s) => {
          content += '<td>' + s + '</td>';
        });
        content += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#ex-table').append(content);
    }
  });
```